# Azure - Cannot dissociate Public IP from Application Gateway

Tags: azure, networking, gateway

I have associated Public IP to Application Gateway.
Now when I want to delete it. I am trying to dissociate it from the application Gateway, but the dissociate button is grayed out.

[image]

How can I delete the public IP?

Comment: Some times just give it some time and try again later.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use PowerShell for that.This support is not available in portal.

You will have to delete Rules, Listener (Remove-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule, Remove-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener in this order), which are associated with the frontend IP configuration and finally issue Remove-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig followed by Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway to achieve this.

Comment: For my terraform script, App gateway Https listener was referring to certificate in keyvault, then for `destroy` it required access to that to service principal doing the deployment as  well.